# Change background-color of div by width (percentage)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my html and my (not correctly working) script:

```js
$( ".bar" ).each( function(){
        var bar = $(".bar").width() / $('.bar').parent().width() * 100;
        var color = '#f5f5f5';
        if (!isNaN(bar)) {
            if (bar > 0) {
                color = 'red';
                alert("0");
            }
            if (bar >= 25) {
                color = 'yellow';
                alert("25");
            }
            if (bar >= 50) {
                color = 'blue';
                alert("50");
            }
            if (bar >= 75) {
                color = 'green';
                alert("75");
            }
            $(this).css({'background' : color});
        }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="bar" style="width: 70%; background: #5283b8;"></div>
<div class="bar" style="width: 33%; background: #5283b8;"></div>
<div class="bar" style="width: 54%; background: #5283b8;"></div>
<div class="bar" style="width: 80%; background: #5283b8;"></div>
<div class="bar" style="width: 12%; background: #5283b8;"></div>
```

I have also created a fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/71rgm4sy/

Whats my fail?

Comment: because  `var bar = $(".bar").width() / $('.bar').parent().width() * 100;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You reference all the bars here:

```
var bar = $(".bar").width() / $('.bar').parent().width() * 100;
```

and you correctly reference the single bar here:

```
$(this).css({'background' : color});
```

The first line should be using `$(this)`. ANd you really whould be using if()/else if()

```js
$(".bar").each(function() {
  var bar = $(this).width() / $(this).parent().width() * 100;
  var color = '#f5f5f5';
  if (!isNaN(bar)) {
    if (bar >= 75) {
      color = 'green';
    }
    else if (bar >= 50) {
      color = 'blue';
    }
    else if (bar >= 25) {
      color = 'yellow';
    }
    else {
      color = 'red';
    }    
    $(this).css({
      'background': color
    });
  }
});
```

```css
.bar {
  height: 3rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="bar" style="width: 70%; background: #5283b8;"></div>
<div class="bar" style="width: 33%; background: #5283b8;"></div>
<div class="bar" style="width: 54%; background: #5283b8;"></div>
<div class="bar" style="width: 80%; background: #5283b8;"></div>
<div class="bar" style="width: 12%; background: #5283b8;"></div>
And thats my (not correctly working) script:
```

Comment: You are right, thats it! What a stupid fail by me **head shake**

Comment: Look at the code to show you how to use if/else if to make it more efficient.

Comment: Yes, you are right! By the way, is the "else if" aso. more quickly or less prone to errors?

Comment: well in yours when the value is 80, it goes into 0, 25, 50, 75 where with mine it just goes into 75.

Answer (score 1):

The updated script should look like this:

```
$( ".bar" ).each( function(){
    var bar = $(this).width() / $(this).parent().width() * 100;
    var color = '#f5f5f5';
    if (!isNaN(bar)) {
        if (bar > 0) {
            color = 'red';
            alert("0");
        }
        if (bar >= 25) {
            color = 'yellow';
            alert("25");
        }
        if (bar >= 50) {
            color = 'blue';
            alert("50");
        }
        if (bar >= 75) {
            color = 'green';
            alert("75");
        }
        $(this).css({'background' : color});
    }
});
```

You were referencing the first element when getting the width, rather than the current element of the `.each(function(){})`.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$( ".bar" ).each( function(){
        // Changed line below to reference $(this) as it was selecting the first element every time
        var bar = $(this).width() / $('.bar').parent().width() * 100;
        var color = '#f5f5f5';
        if (!isNaN(bar)) {
            if (bar > 0) {
                color = 'red';
                // alert("0");
            }
            if (bar >= 25) {
                color = 'yellow';
                // alert("25");
            }
            if (bar >= 50) {
                color = 'blue';
                // alert("50");
            }
            if (bar >= 75) {
                color = 'green';
                // alert("75");
            }
            $(this).css({'background' : color});
        }
});
```

```css
body {
  width:100%;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

.bar {
  height:10px;
  margin-bottom:10px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="bar" style="width: 70%; background: #5283b8;"></div>
<div class="bar" style="width: 33%; background: #5283b8;"></div>
<div class="bar" style="width: 54%; background: #5283b8;"></div>
<div class="bar" style="width: 80%; background: #5283b8;"></div>
<div class="bar" style="width: 12%; background: #5283b8;"></div>
```

It's only selecting the first element. Working on a solution.

Comment: Yes, like epascarello says, but thanks dude for support!